# Как сделать правильно массив чтобы код работал?

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно сделать чтобы метод UpdateSun работал если x = 3,6,9,12.

```
void Update()
{
currentMinutes += (Time.deltaTime * 4);
    if (currentMinutes >= 60)
    {
        currentHours++;
    }

    if (currentMinutes >= 60) { currentMinutes = 0; }
    if (currentHours >= 12) { currentHours = 0; }

    x = (int)currentMinutes;

    Minutes.text = "" + (x);
    Hours.text = "" + (currentHours);

 void UpdateSun()
    {

    float intensityMultiplier = 1;
    if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.23f || currentTimeOfDay >= 0.75f)
    {
        intensityMultiplier = 0;
    }
```

Comment: ну так впишите условие. вы же уже писали if ... еще вставьте)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  было бы так просто все. ничего не происходит. пришлось ставить отдельный таймер для этой хрени.

Comment: Ну значит вы не показали и не объяснили полностью то, что вы хотите сделать. В голове-то у вас может и крутится, но тут в вопросе ничего нет. Так что без понятие что у вас там сложного

Comment: Как сделать вилку, чтобы появилось электричество.  Какие массивы, где они тут?)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, именно для этого я и написал сюда, чтобы мне помогли с массивом. Я хотел сделать массив из которого будет вызываться числа... в общем, жопа полная, я даже не помню зачем так усложнил. К первому таймеру подставил 2 и решил все проблемы